# node.js: standard way to store app's configuration?

Tags: node.js, express

Is there standard ways of storing node.js app's configuration for different environments?

What I did to accomplish this:

created:
node_app_folder/conf/general.js
node_app_folder/conf/development.js
node_app_folder/conf/production.js

general.js:

```
module.exports = {
    setting: "SOME GENERAL SETTING"
   ,setting2: ...
    ...
   // global conf has export method extend that just copies/replaces properties from supplied object
   extend: {...}

}
```

development.js and production.js contain setting specific for the environment.

in app.js:

```
global.conf = require('./conf/general');

// As I use express.js
app.configure('development', function(){       
   global.conf.extend(require('./conf/development'));
   ....
}
app.configure('production', function(){       
   global.conf.extend(require('./conf/producton'));
   ....
}
```

So then in my app's modules I can access app, configuration via global.conf object.

**But I wonder if there are standard ways of doing the described task?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to get the values from JSON files then using [Konphyg](https://github.com/pgte/konphyg) is perfect, here's a nice tutorial about it: http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/31-konphyg-cascading-configuration-files.html

There is no standard way of setting the configuration folder though, each does it in his own way.

Comment: That tutorial is no longer available, unfortunately. Pedro Teixeira started rerecording the tutorials in 2012 but hasn't done many, and hasn't done any since November 2012.

Comment: I am not sure but it looks like the tutorial (or a tutorial very similar by Pedro) is [here](http://vimeo.com/33407241).  Could you please confirm if this is the new location?

Comment: Yup his tutorials are all on Vimeo I think.

Comment: Konphyg is really nice. Here another good tutorial : http://metaduck.com/03-konphyg.html